# Convention for placing isolated classes in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, abstraction

I am writing a Rails application which requires a few Ruby classes to communicate with a third party site, sort of like a custom pseudo API.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to best fit this code into the Rails/MVC paradigm.  I would also like to try to isolate this code from the rest of my app to minimize required changes if the 3rd party site changes.

My initial attempt was to put the communication code in a non-activerecord model called `Search` then add a method to each of my application's database models (`DataModel1` and `DataModel2`) to convert the data to the appropriate form for the 3rd party site.  I don't like this though, because if the format for the 3rd party site changes, I would need to change all of my models.

Ideally, I would like to have a `Search` model with several independent data type classes which correspond to each of my database models, and translate the data to the appropriate format required for the `Search` model.  Basically a `DataType1` class which corresponds to `DataModel1`, and `DataType2` which corresponds to `DataModel2`.

Maybe I'm over thinking this, but where would I put `DataType1` and `DataType2` classes (ideally somewhere associated with `Search` model)?  Is there a better way to organize this code?

Answer (score 0):

After lots of experimentation and reading, here is what I ended up with in case anyone is interested:

I ended up going with a hybrid approach with all data represented in a Search model and submodels, and the connection client for the third party site in a module in the lib folder.

**models/search.rb:**

```
class Search    
  def initialize( params )
    # code to start a new Search on third party site
    @result = SearchApi.example_query( data_type_1_param )
    # more code...
  end
  # other code to assist in parsing of search results
end
```

**models/search/data_type_1.rb:**

```
class Search::DataType1 < Hash 
  def initialize( DataModel1 )
    # code to convert DataModel1 to DataType1 for sending request
  end
end
```

I also have several other Search sub-models which look similar to DataType1.
Additionally, I created Search sub-models to represent the data returned by the Search for ease of use in the program and to have a layer of abstraction.

**models/search/results.rb:**

```
class Search::Results
  def initialize(result_hash)
    @data = result_hash
  end

  def field_1
    # code to parse and display field 1 from @data hash
  end

  def field_2
    # code to parse and display field 2 from @data hash
  end
  #.... etc
end
```

The search model itself may not be completely necessary (most code is in the module and sub-models), but it fits conveniently into the MVC framework for creating and displaying searches.

Finally, I created a module with a client class to actually contact the third party site and conduct the search.  While I may have been able to include this in the Search model, I needed this client to persist (for a number of reasons) and handle multiple searches, while the Search model is recreated for every query.

**lib/search_api.rb:**

```
require 'search_api/client'

module SearchApi 
  class << self
    def client
      @client ||= SearchApi::Client.new()
      @client
    end

    def example_query( data )
      results = client.query( formatted_data )
      # among other code
    end
    # other code to perform validations and interact with client
  end
end
```

**lib/search_api/client.rb:**

```
module SearchApi
  class Client
    include HTTParty

    # code to create and handle connection to Search site
  end
end
```

This method may not follow every best practice and is probably overkill for a lot of circumstances, but seemed to work out well for the issue I was trying to tackle.  If anyone has better ideas to refactor, I'm all ears.